# Не работает загрузчик

Tags: javascript, php, url, http-status-code-404

Вдруг ни с того ни с сего перестали загружаться картинки в новую заявку﻿ . Не работает загрузчик не в админки , не в фронте.

система нормальная, не работает во всех браузерах, права на папку не меняли 100%, картинки на 50 кб, вот код страницы с ошибкой .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На консоле даёт такой ошибка -

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://hut.az/apps/system/js/uploadify/uploadify.php?uploader_type=dropzone&session=d1da60336c3f8b5ac65f2326346fcdd6&element=image&model=data&primary_key_value=&primary_key=
```

Папка и указанный файл существует на этом месте. Права доступа есть.
Путь на етoй файле вот такой:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                //var prevbuttonstatus_'.$Dropzone_name.';
                    var '.$Dropzone_name.' = new Dropzone("div#'.$id.'", 
                    { 
                        maxFilesize: '.$params['max_file_size'].',
                        url: "'.SITEBILL_MAIN_URL.'/apps/system/js/uploadify/uploadify.php?uploader_type=dropzone&session='.$session_code.'&element='.$element.'&model='.$params['element']['table_name'].'&primary_key_value='.$params['element']['primary_key_value'].'&primary_key='.$params['element']['primary_key'].'",
                        '.($params['element']['parameters']['accepted']!='' ? 'acceptedFiles: \''.$params['element']['parameters']['accepted'].'\',' : '').'
                        addRemoveLinks: true
                    });
```

Не знаю как появился ошибка и не могу разобраться в чем проблема.

Comment: Попробуйте все-таки на хостинг другой поставить систему.
Или давайте я скопирую сайт на свой хостинг и посмотрите что все работает норм на нашем хостинге.

Comment: Закончилось выделенное место на жестком диске?